# How to search variable product by its variation id in woocommerce admin product search box?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, admin, variables

I need to search products somehow with ID in admin product search box and if it is a variations Id, then parent product will be listed. So that it can be identified, of which product it belongs too.

How to search product by variations id in woocommerce admin ?

can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have implement the above functionality by modifying the filter "posts_search".

By using bellow code you can search variable products by their variations id in woocommerce admin product search area.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'product_search' );

function product_search( $where ) {

    global $pagenow, $wpdb, $wp;

    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || ! is_search() || ! isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) || 'product' != $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
        return $where;
    }

    $search_ids = array();
    $terms      = explode( ',', $wp->query_vars['s'] );

    foreach ($terms as $term){
        if (is_numeric($term)){
            $post_type = get_post_type( $term );
            if($post_type == 'product_variation'){
                $search_ids[]   =   wp_get_post_parent_id($term);
            }else{
               $search_ids[]   =   $term;
            }
        }
        // Attempt to get a SKU
        $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE %s;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%' ) );
        $sku_to_id = array_merge( wp_list_pluck( $sku_to_id, 'ID' ), wp_list_pluck( $sku_to_id, 'post_parent' ) );

        if (sizeof($sku_to_id) > 0) {
            $search_ids = array_merge($search_ids, $sku_to_id);
        }
     }

     $search_ids = array_filter( array_unique( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) ) );

    if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $where = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ( ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . ")) OR ((", $where );
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Suman!  This is the ONLY code I've been able to find that allows search by SKU from woocommerce admin product search.  Dropped in your code and it worked flawlessly.  Being able to also search by variation ID is a great bonus.